# Redhat-datagrid- 8.4.5 - Unable to have clusters working

Tags: redhat-datagrid

Hi I am new to RedHat DataGrid and have just installed the latest redhat data grid server 8.4.5 on a redhat virtual server on ibm cloud.
The configuration of the Virtual Server is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.x - Minimal Install (amd64).
I have followed the default step in the redhat documentation as per the link: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/8.4/html/data_grid_server_guide/server-getting-started

To keep things simple and to understand the clustering, I have followed the steps outlined above, i.e.
On the same virtual server, I have folder server and server 2 (i.e. I have copied server to have server2).
I have then started the datagrid as follows:
bin/server.sh
bin/server.sh -o 100 -s server2

Each instances are creating a new cluster and not discovering each other. The logs are as follows:

Server log:
[rhdg_user@ipc-paycan-wdc-vs1 redhat-datagrid-8.4.5-server]$ bin/server.sh

2023-12-04 16:45:24,884 INFO  (main) [BOOT] JVM OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Red Hat, Inc. 17.0.9+9-LTS
2023-12-04 16:45:24,894 INFO  (main) [BOOT] JVM arguments = [-server, --add-exports, java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED, -Xlog:gc*:file=/home/rhdg_user/redhat-datagrid-8.4.5-server/server/log/gc.log:time,uptimemillis:filecount=5,filesize=3M, -Xms64m, -Xmx512m, -XX:MetaspaceSize=64M, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dvisualvm.display.name=redhat-datagrid-server, -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.infinispan.server.loader.LogManager, -Dinfinispan.server.home.path=/home/rhdg_user/redhat-datagrid-8.4.5-server, -classpath, :/home/rhdg_user/redhat-datagrid-8.4.5-server/boot/infinispan-server-runtime-14.0.17.Final-redhat-00002-loader.jar, org.infinispan.server.loader.Loader, org.infinispan.server.Bootstrap]
2023-12-04 16:45:24,898 INFO  (main) [BOOT] PID = 149146
2023-12-04 16:45:24,957 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080000: Red Hat Data Grid Server 8.4.5.GA starting
2023-12-04 16:45:24,958 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080017: Server configuration: infinispan.xml
2023-12-04 16:45:24,958 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080032: Logging configuration: /home/rhdg_user/redhat-datagrid-8.4.5-server/server/conf/log4j2.xml
2023-12-04 16:45:25,684 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080027: Loaded extension 'query-dsl-filter-converter-factory'
2023-12-04 16:45:25,685 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080027: Loaded extension 'continuous-query-filter-converter-factory'
2023-12-04 16:45:25,688 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080027: Loaded extension 'iteration-filter-converter-factory'
2023-12-04 16:45:25,689 WARN  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080059: No script engines are available
2023-12-04 16:45:26,238 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN005054: Native IOUring transport not available, using NIO instead: io.netty.incubator.channel.uring.IOUring
2023-12-04 16:45:26,317 WARN  (main) [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2023-12-04 16:45:26,354 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.commons.marshall.ImmutableProtoStreamMarshaller'
2023-12-04 16:45:26,840 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] ISPN000389: Loaded global state, version=14.0.17.Final-redhat-00002 timestamp=2023-12-01T06:13:37.314614542Z
2023-12-04 16:45:27,350 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel `mycluster` with stack `tcp`
2023-12-04 16:45:27,353 INFO  (main) [org.jgroups.JChannel] local_addr: 44d24313-7236-4032-b6b2-ee0ddbe79ce6, name: node1
2023-12-04 16:45:27,379 INFO  (main) [org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK2] server listening on *.57800
2023-12-04 16:45:29,384 INFO  (main) [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] node1: no members discovered after 2001 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
2023-12-04 16:45:29,401 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel mycluster: [node1|0] (1) [node1]
2023-12-04 16:45:29,500 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] ISPN000079: Channel `mycluster` local address is `node1`, physical addresses are `[192.168.1.11:7800]`
2023-12-04 16:45:30,075 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] ISPN000104: Using EmbeddedTransactionManager
2023-12-04 16:45:30,400 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080018: Started connector Resp (internal)
2023-12-04 16:45:30,407 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.server.core.telemetry.TelemetryServiceFactory] ISPN000953: OpenTelemetry integration is disabled
2023-12-04 16:45:30,463 INFO  (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080018: Started connector HotRod (internal)
2023-12-04 16:45:30,566 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080018: Started connector REST (internal)
2023-12-04 16:45:30,582 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] Using transport: Epoll
2023-12-04 16:45:30,665 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080004: Connector SinglePort (default) listening on 127.0.0.1:11222
2023-12-04 16:45:30,665 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080034: Server 'node1' listening on http://127.0.0.1:11222
2023-12-04 16:45:30,722 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080001: Red Hat Data Grid Server 8.4.5.GA started in 5763ms

Server 2 log:
2023-12-04 16:45:59,732 INFO  (main) [BOOT] JVM OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Red Hat, Inc. 17.0.9+9-LTS
2023-12-04 16:45:59,742 INFO  (main) [BOOT] JVM arguments = [-server, --add-exports, java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens, java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED, -Xlog:gc*:file=server2/log/gc.log:time,uptimemillis:filecount=5,filesize=3M, -Xms64m, -Xmx512m, -XX:MetaspaceSize=64M, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dvisualvm.display.name=redhat-datagrid-server, -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.infinispan.server.loader.LogManager, -Dinfinispan.server.home.path=/home/rhdg_user/redhat-datagrid-8.4.5-server, -classpath, :/home/rhdg_user/redhat-datagrid-8.4.5-server/boot/infinispan-server-runtime-14.0.17.Final-redhat-00002-loader.jar, org.infinispan.server.loader.Loader, org.infinispan.server.Bootstrap, -o, 100, -s, server2]
2023-12-04 16:45:59,746 INFO  (main) [BOOT] PID = 149283
2023-12-04 16:45:59,805 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080000: Red Hat Data Grid Server 8.4.5.GA starting
2023-12-04 16:45:59,806 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080017: Server configuration: infinispan.xml
2023-12-04 16:45:59,806 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080032: Logging configuration: /home/rhdg_user/redhat-datagrid-8.4.5-server/server2/conf/log4j2.xml
2023-12-04 16:46:00,554 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080027: Loaded extension 'query-dsl-filter-converter-factory'
2023-12-04 16:46:00,555 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080027: Loaded extension 'continuous-query-filter-converter-factory'
2023-12-04 16:46:00,558 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080027: Loaded extension 'iteration-filter-converter-factory'
2023-12-04 16:46:00,561 WARN  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080059: No script engines are available
2023-12-04 16:46:01,098 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN005054: Native IOUring transport not available, using NIO instead: io.netty.incubator.channel.uring.IOUring
2023-12-04 16:46:01,185 WARN  (main) [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2023-12-04 16:46:01,230 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.commons.marshall.ImmutableProtoStreamMarshaller'
2023-12-04 16:46:01,685 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] ISPN000389: Loaded global state, version=14.0.17.Final-redhat-00002 timestamp=2023-12-01T04:05:45.539884738Z
2023-12-04 16:46:02,148 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel `mycluster` with stack `tcp`
2023-12-04 16:46:02,150 INFO  (main) [org.jgroups.JChannel] local_addr: 435f5cfb-62a5-41a2-ae85-b7490e433359, name: node2
2023-12-04 16:46:02,183 INFO  (main) [org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK2] server listening on *.58000
2023-12-04 16:46:04,188 INFO  (main) [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] node2: no members discovered after 2001 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
2023-12-04 16:46:04,200 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel mycluster: [node2|0] (1) [node2]
2023-12-04 16:46:04,286 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] ISPN000079: Channel `mycluster` local address is `node2`, physical addresses are `[192.168.1.11:7900]`
2023-12-04 16:46:04,888 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] ISPN000104: Using EmbeddedTransactionManager
2023-12-04 16:46:05,173 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080018: Started connector Resp (internal)
2023-12-04 16:46:05,181 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.server.core.telemetry.TelemetryServiceFactory] ISPN000953: OpenTelemetry integration is disabled
2023-12-04 16:46:05,266 INFO  (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080018: Started connector HotRod (internal)
2023-12-04 16:46:05,359 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080018: Started connector REST (internal)
2023-12-04 16:46:05,377 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] Using transport: Epoll
2023-12-04 16:46:05,455 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080004: Connector SinglePort (default) listening on 127.0.0.1:11322
2023-12-04 16:46:05,456 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080034: Server 'node2' listening on http://127.0.0.1:11322
2023-12-04 16:46:05,518 INFO  (main) [org.infinispan.SERVER] ISPN080001: Red Hat Data Grid Server 8.4.5.GA started in 5711ms

Has anyone experienced this issue? Is there a configuration that I am missing? Grateful if someone could help me

Thanks
Aswin

Since this is a straight forward implementation, I was expecting the nodes to discover each other without much configuration on the hosts.